# REST Post of JSON object not handling spaces in date value in java

Tags: java, json, rest, date, post

I'm testing a REST post service with the following unix command:

```
  curl -d "{"begTime":"2012-06-06 01:06:01.744","id":"1"}" http://localhost:8080/Restlet
```

I print the value with the following RESLET print statement:

```
 System.out.println("entity ---------" + jString + "--");
```

when I print the value received in my java app, I see this value:

entity ---------{begTime:2012-06-06--

How can I get the entire date so that it doesn't cut off the rest of the object values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a quoting issue to me; the JSON literal has `"` chars in it. Try this:

```
curl -d '{"begTime":"2012-06-06 01:06:01.744","id":"1"}' http://localhost:8080/Restlet
```

If you're getting seriously into this, consider using something other than shell scripting to do this. That's because it can get seriously awkward to get quoting right with shell scripts, relative to what many other scripting languages (Python, Ruby, Perl, Tcl, …, a very long list) do directly.

Comment: And that looks like a strange JSON literal to me. Quoted numbers? Quoted key names? The only thing that needs quoting in it is the date.

Comment: JSON requires quotes on keys as well.  It's javascript literal objects that don't need quotes. Also, his `id` may not always be numeric.

Comment: @climbage Ah. Shows how often I write JSON literals by hand. :-)

Comment: Hah the only reason I know is because I got hosed when jQuery switched to a more strict JSON parser